# Scala - Read Array in JSON object

Tags: json, scala, parsing, multidimensional-array, playframework-2.0

I am trying to read a part of a JsValue object in scala to perform statistic calculations on it.

I recieve the data under the following format (stringified):

```
{
    "transformType": "z_score",
    "data": [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] // fake values
}
```

After applying a `Json.parse()` I am able to retrieve *z_score* value using

```
(myJson \ "transformation").as[String]
```

but when I try this:

```
(myJson \ "data").as[List[List[Number]]]
```

to extract "data" attribute values, I get the following error:

> No Json deserializer found for type `List[List[Number]]`. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.

Is there another way to achieve this, or how should I "*implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type*"?

I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Where did you get the `Number` class? Try with `Double` or `Long`!

Comment: @insan-e Oh you're right, I found it in the code of another person just above, I don't know where he himself found it... Thanks!

Comment: Maybe @insan-e can put it as answer so OP can accept the solution? :)